# Problem with writing symbols €, £ and zł in package openxlsx using taskscheduleR (by cmd)

Tags: r, cmd, currency, openxlsx, r-taskscheduler

I have problem with `saveworkbook` and my result. I create an excel file with currency using `createstyle(nmFmt='# ##0.00 zł')` and `createstyle(nmFmt='# ##0.00 €')` etc. and then I use `saveWorkbook(wb, xxx)`. In my result I see specific symbols lika a €, £ and zł when I run manually by Rstudio - everything is ok.

Then I create task by package taskscheduleR and my excel file has something like a â¬ or zÂ.

TaskscheduleR run program by cmd. SessionInfo give(): system code page: 65001

I have marked also "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support" in Administrative Settings.

Could you solve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about encoding, maybe some kind of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake):

```
x <- 'z\u0142 £ €'
Encoding(x)
x
Encoding(x) <- 'latin2'
x
Encoding(x) <- 'UTF-8'
x
```

**Result** (paste above code snippet to the `RStudio` console):

```
> 
> x <- 'z\u0142 £ €'
> Encoding(x)
[1] "UTF-8"
> x
[1] "zł £ €"
> Encoding(x) <- 'latin2'
> x
[1] "zÅ‚ Â£ â‚¬"
> Encoding(x) <- 'UTF-8'
> x
[1] "zł £ €"
>
```

Comment: Yep, many thanks! I tried change regedit cmd.exe but that problem was simpler than I thought. I put in my code unicode of this symbol "numFmt='# ##0.00 z\u0142" :)